# Magento 2 Invalid Block Type in Custom Module?

Tags: magento2, layout, custom-block, list.phtml

How can I Rectify Invalid Block Type Error in my custom module?

I created a custom module in Magento 2 for overriding the default product list page with a separate phtml file I am calling them in category update layout XML textarea. It's Working fine.

Now I don't want that so I deleted Layout Update XML textarea code and both my custom module block and phtml. After running setup upgrade and cleared `var/all folders` and `pub/static/all folders` . Still, I am getting **Invalid Block Type** error.

Do I need to delete anything from any tables?

Comment: you have to remove entire var folder

Comment: yes I removed all the folders inside var directory and all the folders inside pub/static folder

Comment: do you revert di.xml? if you do stuff in `di.xml` for override, please revert it to original state.

Comment: Have you disable that module before upgrade ?

Comment: I did not write any di.xml for it.I just call block and template in layout update xml file like this   <referenceContainer name="content">
<referenceBlock name="category.products" remove="true"/>  
<block   template="recipes/list.phtml"
     class="Embitel\CustomListPages\Block\Recipes" name="our_recipes"/>
</referenceContainer> ---Bilal Usean

Comment: No Actually I deleted those files from system and ran setup upgrade command ---Ashish Jagnani

Comment: You have to disable that first, pl follow my answer step and check.

Comment: ok sure --Ashish

Answer (score 0):

Enter the following at the command line to uninstall extension:

```
bin/magento module:disable vendor_module --clear-static-content

bin/magento setup:upgrade

rm -rf var/di

bin/magento setup:di:compile

bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Note : Clear the store cache, clear your browser cache, domain cookies, and refresh the page.

Comment: I followed all the steps in advanced tab module is not showing after completed these steps i removed that folder but No Luck.. :(

Comment: Try to restart apache and clear varnish cache

Comment: The Problem here is Only that category (for which category Update Layout Xml I wrote) showing this Error (Invalid Block type) again that category child categories are perfectly fine.Should we not write Update Layout Xml in category Edit (Admin side) page..? I think If we write Update Layout Xml for a category It is storing somewhere perminently thats y if I delete that Update Layout Xml mentioned block file it is showing error.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I Entered Update Layout Xml snippet for Particular Category in **Store View** selected as "**All Store Views**" so I deleted The Update Layout xml Snippet from where I entered but Error was Not Gone.

The Solution For Above Question is That snippet is also there in currently Working store view So "**Cleared my working Store View Update Layout Xml**" snippet and saved the category.
Refresh cache and Load page :)